# Render input type radio within label for a radiobuttonlist

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, radiobuttonlist

```
<span><span>
        <input type="radio" value="1377">
        <label>
            Enig</label>
    </span><span>
        <input type="radio" value="1378" title="enig">
        <label>
            Delvist enig</label>
    </span><span>
        <input type="radio">
        <label>
            Hverkenenig eller uenig</label>
    </span><span>
        <input type="radio">
        <label>
            Delvist uenig</label>
    </span><span>
        <input type="radio"><label>
            Uenig</label>
</span></span>
```

using CSS3 need to render the above html with the input inside of the label ?

I have tried 
[BootStrapRadioButtonList](http://blog.scottywakefield.net/2012/07/bootstrap-and-aspnet-radiobuttonlist.html) with no luck ?

Problem with the above code is when the browser size is changed the input radio button stays on top while its text moves down !! How do i using css3 render the input within the label ?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, you would format your radio controls as follows:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
    Option three is disabled
  </label>
</div>
```